# Why Flutter don't reuse previously created threads?

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, flutter, dart

I am running time consuming computation inside separate Isolate in Flutter app. I am using `compute` function for this.

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {

  int _result = 0;

  void someAction() async {
    int result = await compute(timeConsumingFunction, 40);
    setState(() {
      _result = result;
    });
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text('$_result'),
          MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Run action"),
              onPressed: someAction
            )
        ]
      );
    }
}
```

Every time user taps the button, inside Xcode profiler I see that new ThreadPool Worker is created.

1. Why Flutter don't reuse previously created ThreadPools?
2. Is it fine to run compute function this way? Or there is better way?
3. Should I care about ThreadPools count?

[image]

Comment: so you want a queue of background tasks executed one-by-one? or want multiple tasks to be run parallely?

Comment: yes, but separate from main isolate with UI

Comment: so use a custom [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html)

Comment: it is easier to use compute function, so I want to know about possible problems

Comment: it is easier but you are limited to its basic usage

Comment: for example you can use [IsolateChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-stream_channel_isolate_channel/IsolateChannel-class.html) to "talk" to your `Isolate` with simple `Stream` / `Sink` API